# Fizz buzz SQL logic error

Tags: sql, oracle

-1 to 100 in SQL and display 'Fizz' if the number is divisible by 3 'Buzz' if divisible by 5 and 'FizzBuzz' if divisible by both. below is my code

```
select 
Case when   Remainder (rownum,3)=0 then 'Fizz'
     when Remainder (rownum,5)=0 then 'Buzz'
     when (remainder (rownum,3)=0 and remainder(ROWNUM,5) = 0) then 'FizzBuzz'
     else rownum end 
from DUAL
Connect by level  <=100;
```

It gives me error - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 18

Comment: cast the rownum to varchar2

Comment: [Code Golf: 1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58969/15968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `ROWNUM` to a string in your `ELSE` case by either:

- `CAST( ROWNUM AS VARCHAR2(3) )`
- `''||ROWNUM`
- `TO_CHAR( ROWNUM )`

You also need the case when it is divisible by both 3 and 5 to be at the top of the list (otherwise the preceding cases will take precedence). Like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN remainder (rownum,15)=0 THEN 'FizzBuzz'
       WHEN Remainder (rownum,3)=0  THEN 'Fizz'
       WHEN Remainder (rownum,5)=0  THEN 'Buzz'
       ELSE TO_CHAR(rownum)
       END 
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100;
```

However, you can shorten the code a lot (taken from an answer I posted for [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58969/15968)):

```
SELECT NVL(
         DECODE(MOD(LEVEL,3),0,'Fizz')||DECODE(MOD(LEVEL,5),0,'Buzz'),
         ''||LEVEL
       )
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL<101
```

Comment: Thank you so much you made my day!

Answer (score 2):

It's in your else statement. Rownum is a NUMBER whereas Fizz, Buzz, and FizzBuzz are CHAR.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
Case when   Remainder (rownum,3)=0 then 'Fizz'
     when Remainder (rownum,5)=0 then 'Buzz'
     when (remainder (rownum,3)=0 and remainder(ROWNUM,5) = 0) then 'FizzBuzz'
     else ''||rownum end 
from DUAL
Connect by level  <=100;
```

or

```
select 
Case when   Remainder (rownum,3)=0 then 'Fizz'
     when Remainder (rownum,5)=0 then 'Buzz'
     when (remainder (rownum,3)=0 and remainder(ROWNUM,5) = 0) then 'FizzBuzz'
     else to_char(rownum) end 
from DUAL
Connect by level  <=100;
```

Comment: de-credit for missing the wrong order of case expression branches (see MT0's answer for explanation).

Comment: @mathguy A little harsh as this does answer the issue of the `ORA-00932` exception which was the main focus of the question.